# how to do in java curl -vkv 'https://doaminname.asmx' --key privatekey_com.key --cert-type der --cert doaminname_certifile_der.cer

Tags: java, security, soap, openssl, certificate

How can I create a java client to access the SOAP service by  'https://doaminname.asmx' and they gave me doaminname_certifile_der.cer file i can access the service together with my private key and doaminname_certifile_der.cer file using curl command.

**curl -vkv 'https://doaminname.asmx' --key privatekey_com.key --cert-type der --cert doaminname_certifile_der.cer**

How I can use both file to post request in Java.

The key file generated using openssl,  openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048

Comment: you need to search about "how to run command-line commands from java"

Comment: I want to know how to used both private key file and cer file while calling the SOAP serivce